# SQL Query - Combined rows with selective columns [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
Game | Name | Result | Stage
  1      A       W      F
  1      B       L      0
  2      C       L      F
  2      D       W      0
  3      E       L      0
  3      F       W      0
```

The output I am looking for:

```
Game | Name | Result | Stage
  1      A       W      F
  2      D       W      F
```

I only want to see the winners (W) from the results of stage F.

I can do this via joins (which isn't very fast):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE Stage = 'F'
  ) AA
  JOIN MyTable
    ON AA.Game = MyTable.Game AND AA.Result <> MyTable.Result
```

..but I am wondering if there is an easier and more efficient way to do it. Plus this requires I do some more filtering afterwards.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But (at the risk of stating the obvious) 2 is stage 0

Comment: Yes it is. And I need to get the winner of stage 2, but also the winners of all games of stage F, if that makes sense.

Comment: Nope. I don't understand that statement.

Comment: John Bollinger already answered my question below, but I'll make my question clearer.

The table shows a list of games. Game 1 and 2 are stage F games. As logic would dictate, rows 1-4 show have F in column stage. But the table is constructed in a way that only the first row for the game indicates the stage.

So if I were to query for all games of stage F, I wouldn't get the winner of game 2. If I were to look for all winners, I would get winner of game 3, which I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform a job of this sort without a self-join or an equivalent, you would want to use SQL window functions, which MySQL does not support.  The join you are using is not too bad, but this would be a little simpler:

```
SELECT
  players.Game AS Game,
  players.Name AS Name,
  'W' AS Result,
  'F' as Stage
FROM
  MyTable stage
  JOIN MyTable players
    ON stage.Game = players.Game
WHERE
  stage.stage = 'F'
  AND players.result = 'W'
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer since it answers my question, that it can't be done in MySQL without joins or equivalent methods. I do find my query to be simpler though. Thanks for the response.

Comment: This is a better answer (which is probably why my answer is so similar - albeit much later) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With "The winners only from stage F" you only need:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE stage="F" and result="W";
```

Your own result example however also shows name "D" which is not a winner in stage F.

Comment: No no....D is the winner of game 2. However row 3, instead of row 4, shows that Game 2 is of stage F. I know the table itself isn't well structured to start with, but that is what I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to see the winners (W) from the results of stage F you don't need a join. The following statement will work:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable where Stage='F' AND Result= 'W'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a subquery :

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  Result = 'W'
  AND Game IN (SELECT Game FROM MyTable WHERE Stage = 'F')
```

Comment: A subquery with IN takes way longer than a join.

Comment: Performance depends on many things and the newest versions of Mysql have "subquery materialization" to improve performance of these types of queries  ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html ).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of this optimization.

Comment: IN with "subquery materialization" is still way slower than a join.
IN translates in an OR...OR list. subquery materialization translates into a tmp object in larger cases written to disk. Still way slower than a good join query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.Game
     , y.Name
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.game = x.game
   AND y.result = 'w'
 WHERE x.stage = 'f';
```